# Find K subsets of a list with elements 1...N while preserving the order of the elements

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, combinatorics

Given a list of integers from 1...N I am trying to find K subsets of the elements, while preserving the order of the elements. For example, when N = 4 and K = 2:

[1] [2, 3, 4]

[1, 2] [3, 4]

[1, 2, 3] [4]

[1, 2, 3, 4] []

Would be the correct output. 
So far I've gotten the first column of possibilities. But I am struggling to get the correct logic.

```py
    final = [['' for x in range(K)] for y in range(N)]
    i = 0
    for k in range(0, K):
        # row tracker
        i = 0
        while i < N:
            if k > 0:
                st = len(final[i][k - 1])
            else:
                st = 0
            for j in range(0, N):
                tmp = ""
                prefix = chemicals[:j + 1]
                tmp = tmp.join(str(i) for i in prefix)
                final[i][k] = tmp
                i += 1
        print
```

Again, correct output would be:

[1] [2, 3, 4]

[1, 2] [3, 4]

[1, 2, 3] [4]

[1, 2, 3, 4] []

Where a set can be empty.

Update: This is the correct output for N=4, K=3

```
[1] [2] [3, 4]
[1] [2, 3] [4]
[1] [2, 3, 4] []
[1, 2] [3] [4]
[1, 2] [3, 4] []
[1, 2, 3] [4] []
[1, 2, 3, 4] [] []
```

Comment: Would `[1,2,3,4] [] []` be part of the solution to N=4, K=3?

Comment: Yes that would be correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a function that iterates an index from a given starting number, defaulting to `1`, to `n`, yields a range of numbers from the starting number to the index, and recursively joins the subsets from the recursive call with a starting index of one higher and one less subset, until either starting index is greater than `n` or `k` becomes `1`, at which point the remaining range should be yielded:

```
def get_subsets(n, k, s=1):
    if s > n or k == 1:
        yield [list(range(s, n + 1))] + [[] for _ in range(1, k)]
        return
    for i in range(s, n + 1):
        for subsets in get_subsets(n, k - 1, i + 1):
            yield [list(range(s, i + 1))] + subsets
```

so that:

```
for s in get_subsets(4, 2):
    print(*s)
```

outputs:

```
[1] [2, 3, 4]
[1, 2] [3, 4]
[1, 2, 3] [4]
[1, 2, 3, 4] []
```

and that:

```
for s in get_subsets(4, 3):
    print(*s)
```

outputs:

```
[1] [2] [3, 4]
[1] [2, 3] [4]
[1] [2, 3, 4] []
[1, 2] [3] [4]
[1, 2] [3, 4] []
[1, 2, 3] [4] []
[1, 2, 3, 4] [] []
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. I don't think n=4 and k=3 produces the correct output. There should be a case where 2 of the 3 sets are empty: [1, 2, 3, 4] [] []

Side question: is there a way to do this without generators? Like in a purely recursive or iterative way?

Comment: Glad to be of help. Can you update your question with your expected output for n=4 and k=3 then?

Comment: Sorry accidentally submitted the comment too soon (tried to edit). Output would be:
[1] [2] [3, 4]...

[1] [2, 3] [4]...

[1] [2, 3, 4] []...

[1, 2] [3] [4]...

[1, 2] [3, 4] []...

[1, 2, 3] [4] []...

[1, 2, 3, 4] [] []...

Comment: Ah I see. Fixed it then.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple list comprehension with slicing should suffice. You may want to use `itertools.combinations` as well:

```
import itertools

N = 4
K = 2

elements = list(range(1, N + 1))
final = [[elements[a:b] for a, b in zip([0] + cuts, cuts + [N])]
                        for cuts in (list(c) for c in itertools.combinations(elements, K - 1))]

for x in final:
    print(*x)
```

Output:

```
[1] [2, 3, 4]
[1, 2] [3, 4]
[1, 2, 3] [4]
[1, 2, 3, 4] []
```

Comment: Hi, I updated my output. There should be another line of output with two empty sets when N=4, K=3